# Why there are two types of medium (YPGlu and YPGal) in the *K. lactis* Protein Expression Kit?

Tags: yeast, protein-expression

I am planning to use the *K. lactis* Protein Expression Kit from NEB for the expression of certain protein. I am not experienced with working with yeast. I started by reading the manual for this kit and I am a bit confused with the fact that there are two types of medium: YPGlucose and YPGalactose. Do I understand correctly that YPGlucose medium should be used for cell propagation while YPGalactose should be used for protein expression and if so, why is that?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. In particular, it isn't reasonable to expect users of this site to find and read this manual for you! At a minimum you should make sure you've read all the entire material and then provide quotes and links for the relevant sections that you are having trouble with. ——— The answer is probably in there (in particular pay attention to the promoter on the expression vector that drives expression of the transgene). Thanks! 

Comment: NEB also has very good customer support, you can always call or email them to get in contact with the people that actually design and produce the kits.